# About definition of measure 0

Tags: real-analysis, definition

> Definition: Let A be a subset of $R^n $. We say A has measure zero in $ R^n $ if for every $\epsilon >0 $ , there is a covering $ Q_1,Q_2... $  of A by countably many rectangles such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} v(Q_i) <\epsilon $$. If this inequality holds, we often say that the total volume of the rectangles $ Q_1,Q_2... $  is less than $\epsilon $.

My question is is the measure 0 equivalent to say that the volume is 0?

Comment: Volume is only defined for rectangles. Here measure zero is defined for an arbitrary subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: how do you define "volume of a set $A \subset \Bbb{R}^n$" for an arbitrary $A$?  The concept of "$A$ has (Lebesgue) measure zero in $\Bbb{R}^n$" is meant to formalize the idea that the set is very small/negligible in some specific quantitative sense. (like for example a single point set should intuitively of course be negligible in comparison to the whole $\Bbb{R}^n$, or for example, the $x$-axis should be "negligible" in comparison to the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$)

Comment: It depends what you mean by volume. If you refer to the Jordan content of a "well-behaved" (Jordan-admissible) set, then it is indeed true that the Jordan content and the Lebesgue measure agree in this case. However, there are sets that have no well-defined Jordan content, because they are not admissible, but still have a well-defined Lebesgue measure. For instance, $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ has measure zero, as it is a countable set, but it is not an admissible set in the sense of Jordan.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, that's what I was looking for.